# Cannot deploy GAE changes after switching to "gcloud app deploy"

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I was happily using `appcfg.py` until recently everyone had to switch to `gcloud app deploy`. But now when I try to deploy, no changes seem to happen.

For example if I edit my app's `get` method to be just

```
class Main(webapp.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.response.out.write('Hello StackOverflow?')
        return
```

And then do `gcloud app deploy`; output shows one file changed, as expected:

```
descriptor:      [/Users/bemmu/Dropbox/b2/candytools/appengine/app.yaml]
source:          [/Users/bemmu/Dropbox/b2/candytools/appengine]
target project:  [bemmu1-hrd]
target service:  [default]
target version:  [20200912t045337]
target url:      [https://bemmu1-hrd.appspot.com]


Do you want to continue (Y/n)?  

Beginning deployment of service [default]...
╔════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╗
╠═ Uploading 1 file to Google Cloud Storage                 ═╣
╚════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╝
File upload done.
Updating service [default]...done.                                             
Setting traffic split for service [default]...done.                            
Deployed service [default] to [https://bemmu1-hrd.appspot.com]
```

However nothing changes. My website still stays as it was. I have confirmed I have the correct project selected. I also confirmed that the latest version is the only one running:

[image]

I have also tried fetching with cURL to make sure my browser is not caching anything. I also confirmed on cloud.google.com that the source changed (version number differs because this is from another attempt):

[image]

Any ideas? It's very painful to test this, as each deploy attempt takes over 4 minutes.  I have a feeling I'm making some obvious silly mistake here.

Comment: If you go to `https://bemmu1-hrd.appspot.com`, do you get the new site?  Try deleting your instances and trying again. Although from your version naming schema, it looks like these are fresh instances. Also looks like you're only using the `default` service, which eliminates the "wrong service deployed" possibility. And "candytools" holds the "Bemmu" code?

Comment: Yes candytools is the proper code for bemmu1-hrd

Comment: I deleted the instance but didn't change anything. Yet if I view source on cloud.google.com I can see the source has changed.

Comment: And no I don't get the new site at https://bemmu1-hrd.appspot.com either @GAEfan

Comment: Decided to try delete *.pyc files before deploy, and that solved it. I hadn't tested the changes locally so my .pyc files didn't have the changes. I'm surprised GAE just used those, appcfg.py didn't have this issue. Thanks for rubber ducking @GAEfan , much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You need to delete *.pyc files before deploy, otherwise GAE will use your stale cached ones instead of rebuilding them.